# Validate Purchase in Microsoft Store for Subscriptions?

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, app-store, windows-store

We are reviewing Microsoft Store integration for some of the apps of our organisation. As per our current understanding of the Store, we are planning to use [Get subscriptions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user) server to server API for fetching a user's purchases and verifying if the purchase to the claimed product is currently `Active` or not.

The API requires a `StoreID` to be passed which is the user identifier for the user Microsoft Store user logged in to the store. The app needs to generate this `StoreID` by calling [some API](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getcustomerpurchaseidasync) from the Windows SDK and store it locally.

Once the purchase is successful from the store, the `StoreID` is sent to our servers in a API called `ClaimPurchase`, which utilises the above server-server `Get Subscriptions for a user` API to fetch the subscriptions for verification.

Problem:

User A (user in our system) logs in and purchases the subscription and captures the `ClaimPurchase` call (through some proxy set on the device) to retrieve the StoreID.

User A sells user B the StoreID. User B logs in to the app (again proxied on the device), fetch their authentication parameters (some access token) and use a HTTP client to make the `ClaimPurchase` call with the `access token` and `StoreID`.

When the call is validated from the server to server call, it will show that the subscriptions for the current user are active.

One way to solve this is, that we maintain a `StoreID -> UserId` mapping whenever a successful `ClaimPurchase` is made. And StoreID be verified that it belongs to the same user.

But just in case user A also generates a new StoreID, say `S2` at the same time (when S1 was generated) and sells to user B instead of `S1`. User B uses StoreID `S2` while making the claim.

How do we handle this scenario. The API response for `Get Subscriptions for User` provides a `id` field (subscription id) and a `beneficiary_id` which can be mapped to the application user id. But this works only if the two never change for a subscription in their active states.

My question falls back to: Does `id` and `beneficiary_id` change?

Also, is there a better method of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a user purchases a subscription add-on or an app depends on whether the license they acquire is active or not, not depends on the Store ID .Purchase a subscription add-on require the Store ID(enabled in your code behind), rather than a user purchase and get the Store ID.The Store ID belongs to the developer not the customers.So there should be no possible for users to buy or sell Store ID to log in your app/add-on.

When you enable the subscription add-on for your app,you should follow the steps:

1.Determines whether the customer already has an active license for the subscription.(AppLicense,AddOnLicenses)

2.Use [StoreProduct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproduct) object that represents the subscription you want to purchase on behalf of the customer.

3.The code then determines whether a trial is available for the subscription.

4.Call  [RequestPurchaseAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproduct.RequestPurchaseAsync) method to request the purchase of the subscription

For more details please refer to document: [Enable subscription add-ons for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app)